# What could I possibly be doing wrong with this update statement

Tags: mysql, update

```
UPDATE pcdbak
    SET
        pcdbak.Title = pcd.Title
    FROM pcd, pcdbak
    WHERE
        pcdbak.eCommNum = pcd.eCommNum
```

This was the error message:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM pcd, pcdbak    WHERE       pcdbak.eCommNum = pcd.eCommNum' at
>   line 4

Comment: Can you post the table schemas? Perhaps the column eCommNum does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use proper `UPDATE JOIN` syntax

```
UPDATE pcdbak INNER JOIN pcd
ON pcdbak.eCommNum = pcd.eCommNum
SET pcdbak.Title = pcd.Title;
```

or

```
UPDATE pcdbak INNER JOIN pcd
USING (eCommNum)
SET pcdbak.Title = pcd.Title;
```

or (to fix your query, 1) remove `FROM`, 2) move both tables next to `UPDATE`)

```
UPDATE pcd, pcdbak
    SET
        pcdbak.Title = pcd.Title
    WHERE
        pcdbak.eCommNum = pcd.eCommNum
;
```

Give it a Try !!!